# Data bind over in array in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, knockout.js

I have an array as follows:

```
self.arrayObj : Array[2]
  >0:Object
   >Display1
    ->InnerObjects
   >__proto
  >1:Object
   >Display2
    -->InnerObjects
```

My interntion is to display "Display1" and "Display2" which are strings
I am doing the html binding as follows:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: self.arrayObj">
<span data-bind="text:$data[0]"></span>
</div>
```

How can I iterate over the array and display only texts?

Comment: `$data[0]` attempts to get a value from a property named `0` in your two `Object`s. Your question does not make clear what `Display1` and `Display2` are. Are they property names or string values? `{ name: "Display1" }` can be accessed using `text: name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to answer my own question.

It is not a simple thing when we want to bind the object with dynamic keys and values in the UI using **Knockout js**. If we have the fixed keynames then its easy.
What I did was , converted the json object to 2-D array :

In the .js file

```
var 2Darray = jsonObject.map(function(val) { 
     var keyname = Object.keys(val)[0];
     var value = val[keyname];
     return [keyname,value];
});
```

In the html file , we can bind it two times in a loop:

```
<div data-bind:"foreach:2Darray">

  <div data-bind:"foreach: $data">

   <div data-bind:"text:$data[0]">
   <div data-bind:"foreach: $data[1]">
     <div data-bind:"text:$data.val">
      </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your array is just an array of strings you should do the following:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: self.arrayObj">
    <span data-bind="text:$data"></span>
</div>
```

In case your array is an array of objects which have for example a property 'Name', which is a string, then you do it like this. Knockout knows you're inside the foreach so it knows which element you're at while looping.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: self.arrayObj">
     <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: data-bind="text:Name" will not work since the property Name is no where

Comment: It was an example because you did not show us what arrayObj exactly is. If it is an array of String then the first sample is what you need.

Comment: Did this help you? If so, please mark it as the answer.